# How does a column-oriented DBMS filter on multiple columns?

Tags: index, columnstore, olap, scan

I'm learning how column-oriented DBMS / "columnars" work for OLAP situations.

Let's say we have a log of millions of transactions with 3 columns: `timestamp`, `shop`, `product`, and we want to know the products sold in the shop `A` in a certain time range:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product FROM data
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1600010000 AND 1602678400 
            AND shop = 'A'
```

This will be stored like this (admittedly, this is more or less an abstraction):

```
timestamp [1600000000, 1600000005, 1600000005, 1600000017, 1600000018, ... ]
shop      [A, A, B, D, C, ...]
product   [X153, S76D, TYA6, LKJ6, SDH7, ...]
```

For this query:

- I totally get how we can achieve fast lookup *by timestamp*, since this column is sorted: with 2 [dichotomic searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search) we can find the **index** for which timestamp=1600010000 and 1602678400. With **less than 30 read operations of a few bytes**, it's done, we have `rowid_start`, `rowid_end` (I don't know if it's still called rowid in the context of a columnar) that make the boundaries of this time-range. The key thing is that we *haven't* had to read megabytes of data, but just a few bytes.
- **Question: then, how can a columnar filter by `shop = 'A'`? Do we have to read **each entry** of the column `shop` in the range `rowid_start .. rowid_end` to test if it's `A` or not?** This could potentially be hundreds of MB or GB of data.

TL;DR: once we have filtered by one column, how can a columnar do a second-column-filtering, without doing a FULL SCAN?

Comment: Do you have a particular DBMS in mind?

Comment: @Lennart I'm just starting with "columnars" (https://towardsdatascience.com/columnar-stores-when-how-why-2d6759914319), so for now I only have looked at ClickHouse, MonetDB, DuckDB (which aims at being Sqlite for OLAP), but I also heard about [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/).

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not realise that you referred to a product contrary to a principle. FWIW, many traditional  RDBMS also offer the possabilty to use column oriented tables these days. If you are doing a mix of OLTP and OLAP that may be worth investigating as well.

Comment: @Lennart Oh I did not know that. I'm just starting with OLAP / column-oriented DB, so I'm not decided for one specific software yet. Which traditional RDBMS allow column-oriented mode? Is it true for MySQL? Sqlite? PostgreSQL?

Comment: I dont think postgres has it out of the box (I may be wrong), but you can have a look at https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2014/04/03/columnar-store-for-analytics/ Mariadb https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-columnstore/  There are also commersial vendors that offer free versions, see for example https://www.ibm.com/products/db2-database/developers or https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/columnstore-index-standard-and-express-editions-with-sql-server/ba-p/384966

Comment: I dont think one would choose sqllite for a typical use case that would benefit from a column store, but thats just guessing.

Comment: I would consider this a use case where a columnstore would work against you, not for you.  A far better approach is using a index-organized table/clustered index of `(Shop, Product, Timestamp)` or possibly `(Shop, Timestamp, Product)` depending on how things are versioned.

Comment: @bbaird It's exactly what I'm using right now: an index-organized table (a `WITHOUT ROWID`-table in the Sqlite terminology) indexed with `(Shop, timestamp, product)` as PRIMARY KEY, I'm happy to see we arrived to the same conclusion (at least it shows my first attempts were not totally nonsense :)). I wanted to benchmark if a column-oriented DB would add a benefit when we have millions of rows. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @Basj In my experience, column-oriented isn't really that great for versioned data, and can be of limited benefit versus explicitly partitioning the table vertically (6NF) for other cases.  It's great if you have a very wide dataset you can't invest the time in normalizing properly and want to improve ad-hoc query performance against small subsets of the data.

Comment: Thank you @bbaird. What do you mean by versioned? I'm logging millions of events, in a chronological order, without modification of past events (no versioning). Could you elaborate your comment into an answer (it seems interesting)?

Comment: @Basj - If you're snapshotting data and storing it as a time series, you're storing *versions* of the data.  Whether or not you condense the data later isn't material.

Comment: A quick search has shown me that various SQL products use the term "columnstore/column store" for this kind of architecture, and this site already has a tag called `columnstore`. I've added the tag to your question and also removed your opening remark about tags. Feel free to roll back my edit if you are not happy with it.

Comment: @AndriyM Thank you very much! PS: Is `columnstore` the same thing a `column-oriented` DB?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would first of all understand the term "columnstore" to mean an architecture, a type of storage. You can have a columnstore table, a columnstore index. If an entire database is configured to use columnstore as the default storage method, I guess it would be fair to call it a column-oriented database, but that's my personal understanding. Without much practical experience working with columnstore as an architecture, I may not be using the terminology entirely correctly. Hopefully someone else comes along and corrects me where I'm wrong. Sorry about potential confusion.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few factors which reduce the horror of a full scan of the `shop` column.

1. The values of each column can be stored in the same order: the first value of timestamp corresponds to the first value in shop and to the first in product; the second to the second to the second, and so on. So a fast lookup that gives the offsets for the start and end of the timestamp range also gives the offset of the corresponding values in shop. The search can jump straight to that offset in the list of shop values, if shop codes are fixed length or can be coerced into being fixed length. More on this soon.
2. For disk-oriented rather than fully in-memory systems, meta data can be held to show which disk files correspond to what offsets for each column. So IO is limited to only the files necessary.
3. IO is still block-oriented and all the shop codes are contiguous on disk. One (relatively fast) sequential read will return a *lot* of shop codes into memory.
4. Those codes can be stored contiguously in memory, which is very pre-fetch- and processor cache-friendly.
5. Compression. Even if the shop codes are quite long or of variable length, likely there will be relatively few unique values (Walmart has fewer than [12,000 stores](https://corporate.walmart.com/our-story/our-locations)). Dictionary compression can be applied, which maps each long string to a much shorter fixed length integer. The mapping table is held once and it is these integers which become the values held in column array. Run-length encoding can further reduce the size of the "shop" array, producing a virtuous feedback with file size, memory and CPU cache utilisation.

The RowID you speak about is a useful visualisation but need not be physically implemented. Since tuples' columns are stored in the same order, the offsets perform the function the RowID would. For multi-predicate queries it is unlikely an actual array of integers representing offsets would be built for each predicate and the intersection of these computed. Rather, each predicate would produce a bitmap and these bitmaps would be AND-ed (or OR-ed) to produce the final predicate. Each bit represents the offset of a tuple that satisfies the predicate.

One of the earliest column stores ([C-Store](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs345d-01/rl/cstore.pdf)) allowed for redundant storage of column sets, each of which could be sorted differently to facilitate fast predicate lookup. I know of no recent system which implements this, but it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 3):

Columns-organized storage engines are vastly different in implementation, so a general answer to your question is hardly possible. At a very basic level though a DBMS with a modestly advanced query optimizer would implement something like this:

1. Values of each column are stored together (as you have mentioned). Each value has some sort of a pointer (think ROWID), which is common to all columns of that specific row; this ID allows the engine to put back together rows decomposed for columnar storage.
2. Evaluation of each column-level predicate produces a list of "row IDs" matching the predicate. In your case there will be two lists, one for rows containing matching `"timestamp"` values, the other for `shop`.
3. "Row ID" lists from multiple predicates are coalesced into a single list. In your case this will be the intersection of two lists.
4. Values of additional columns in the select list (`product` in your example) are fetched using the final "row IDs" and returned to the client.

For an in-depth review of one possible implementation of a column-organized storage and query engine you can check this [article from Db2 developers](https://researcher.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-ipandis/vldb13db2blu.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About your point 2.: for the `timestamp` column, no problem, only a few lookups in O(log n) allow to find the 2 boundaries "row ID" of this time-range, since this timestamp column is sorted. But for the unsorted `shop` column, it seems to require a (horrible!) full scan. (Yes about 3., 4., a set 'intersection' works + and a final fetching in the original table for the additional columns).

Comment: Like I said, implementations differ, but in any case  "a horrible full scan" (of whatever you think is scanned) is unlikely. Read about internal optimisation techniques used by your chosen columnar engine.