# Columnar DBMS and issue understanding multiple where constraints

Tags: join, columnstore

I read a lot about columnar DMBS and perfectly understand that they are great for researches on a column.
This [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282596/how-does-a-column-oriented-dbms-filter-on-multiple-columns) has a partial answer.

Now, say I have a DMBS with 3 columns A, B and C.

Doing a query on each column should be very fast given a proper implementation.
But my question is about joining data between A B and C in a query such as
**select A,B,C where A > 15 and B == 9 and C < 67**.

If each column has millions of rows containing same values, how can a join be made to be very fast?
What if queries not necessarily cover A, B and C, but "A and C" or even "B and C"

Same question with a projection on 30 columns with possible empty ones?

I hardly get how a join can be efficient because it looks like a scan to me.

So, should I understand that column oriented DBMS is good for only finding data on one column?
Could you please share your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

Columnstores excel at scanning.  And while certain queries are super-fast on columnstores because of partition elimination, column elimination, or segment elimination, most queries rely on the fact that millions of rows can be scanned more quickly in a columnstore than a row store.

For instance, in SQL Server column segments are highly compressed, and filters are applied in with batch-mode query operators, which operate on vectors of column values instead of individual data points, and even leverage [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) CPU instructions.

Answer (score 1):

> in a query such as `select A,B,C where A > 15 and B == 9 and C < 67`

there is no join. What happens, in general terms, is the engine scans each column for the indicated values and compiles lists of row IDs or bitmaps of matching blocks, then applies logical operations, `and`s in your example, to those lists/bitmaps, obtaining the final set of matching rows/blocks.